# MySQL latest records with condition

Tags: mysql

I need to get the latest records, which are repeated more than two times.

structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tag_n` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_n` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_n`),
  KEY `tag` (`tag`),
  KEY `post_n` (`post_n`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Records:

```
SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY post_n DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(post_n) AS tags_count 
FROM tags
GROUP BY tag HAVING tags_count>=2
ORDER BY post_n DESC LIMIT 5
```

[image]

But I get wrong results, latest must be "xpro", can't understand what`s wrong.

Any ideas?

p.s.
sorry for my english.

Comment: The first thing that I notice is that you're asking for records that are repeated more than two times, but your query looks for records repeated more than one time (`>=2` rather than `>2`). is that it? otherwise, you should probably show us what result you're getting and what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, already corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(*)AS tags_count FROM
(
  SELECT post_n, tag FROM tags
  ORDER BY post_n DESC LIMIT 20
) AS temp
GROUP BY tag HAVING tags_count>=2
ORDER BY post_n DESC LIMIT 5
```

Of course need to change limit in the first selection, otherwise there will be plenty to choose from.

P. S.
Sorry that is poorly formulated question, my english very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(post_n) AS tags_count ,max(post_n) as max_post_n
FROM tags
GROUP BY tag HAVING tags_count>=2
ORDER BY max_post_n DESC LIMIT 5
```

Version 2 Faster SELECT slower insert. Stats updates online

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tag_n` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_n` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_n`),
  KEY `tag` (`tag`),
  KEY `post_n` (`post_n`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags_stats` (
  `tag` varchar(30),
  `tags_count` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `max_post_n` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;


Pseudo code :

INSERT INTO tags(tag,post_n) VALUES(tag_value, post_n_value);

row = SELECT * FROM tags_stats WHERE tag=tag_value;
if not row:
    INSERT INTO tags_stats(tag,tags_count,max_post_n) VALUES(tag_value,1,post_n_value);
else:
    if row.max_post_n < post_n_value
        UPDATE tags_stats SET tags_count=tags_count+1,
          max_post_n=post_n_value WHERE tag=tag_value;
    else:
        UPDATE tags_stats SET tags_count=tags_count+1,
          WHERE tag=tag_value;
#######################################
SELECT * FROM tags_stats ORDER BY max_post_n DESC;
```

Comment: It looks like what I need. Did`t know about this method of ordering, thank you!